# Casting NULL pointers

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Please consider the following program. Given four different pointers, it prints them as unsigned long.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

int main(){
    char        *pc = NULL;
    int         *pi = NULL;
    double      *pd = NULL;
    long double    *pld = NULL;
    printf("%5lu%5lu\n%5lu%5lu\n%5lu%5lu\n%5lu%5lu\n",
        (ulong)(pc + 1),(ulong)(pi + 1),
        (ulong)(pd + 1),(ulong)(pld + 1),  
        (ulong)(pc + 1),(ulong)(pld + 1)
        (ulong)(pc), (ulong)(pc));
    return 0;
}
```

Well, I am not totally sure that I gave the results the correct meaning:

```
1    4
8   16
1   16
0    0
```

With `pc + 1` and `pi + 1` we have `1` and `4` respectively. My system, most likely, assign 1 byte for a pointer to char and 4 for a pointer to int. On this base, I deduced that the program gives me the amount of memory assigned made available to these pointers.

But `pc` and `pi` return both zero. Why? If my deduction was correct, should not `1` and `4` bytes of memory be assigned in any case to `pc` and `pi`?

Comment: A pointer isn't assigned any **memory**, it just points to a location which might or might not be valid (i.e. memory actually present and usable by your program).

Comment: The relevant parts is the pointer to ***char*** and pointer to ***int***. To get the byte offset to a specific element, the compiler adds the size of the type being *pointed to*. So for a pointer to `int` the compiler adds a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Then, if I got it correctly, the program returns how big the pointed location is, according to the _type *_ of the pointer.

Comment: And that you can easily get by just doing e.g. `sizeof *pi`.

Comment: Great, I am on a couple of tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is a bit strange:

> If my deduction was correct, should not 1 and 4 bytes of memory be assigned in any case to pc and pi?

There's no "memory assigned" to a pointer. A pointer is just an object containing an *address*. This might be an address of an actually usable object, or it might be invalid. If it's `NULL`, it's guaranteed to be invalid.

Representations of different pointer types are allowed to be different, although they rarely are in practice. If they are, it's guaranteed you can convert `NULL` of different types to each other, it will stay a *null pointer*. Apart from that, the compiler uses the type information associated with a pointer to compute indices. If you add `1` to a pointer pointing to a type of size `8`, the actual value will increase by `8`.

The following two quotes from the standard seem relevant to your question:

**§6.3.2.3 p3**:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>   `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>   to a pointer to any object or function.

**§6.3.2.3 p6**:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

So, your code is *implementation defined*. Converting `0` to `void *` gives you a *null pointer*, therefore it's not unreasonable that converting a null pointer to some integer type gives indeed `0`, but this isn't guaranteed.

Strictly speaking, the expressions adding an offset to `NULL` are even **undefined** behavior: For pointer arithmetics to be well-defined, the result of the expression must point to an existing array element or one past that -- that's of course impossible with `NULL` which isn't a valid pointer in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing `pc`  without adding anything to it, so basically you're printing `NULL` cast back to (the non-standard type) `ulong`, which gives you 0. This is not an unreasonable result, since "all bits zero" might be how the compiler implements `NULL`, and doing a straight bit-for-bit conversion to an unsigned integer would give you zero.

Comment: That's really interesting passage, the one you pointed. It could be the procedure my `gcc` compiler adopts to manage this cast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if it made me surely better comprehend the issue and actually answer the question, I ended up choosing Felix Palman's one. It goes a little deeper, actually solving few mistakes that were at the base of my un-comprehension. In any case, +1 for made me think about the need to better learn the compiler behaviour!

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithmetic on a pointer not pointing to an array is Undefined Behavior. So you could receive any results in first 3 lines of output, since all your pointers point to NULL.

The 4th line of output simply prints the value of NULL on your platform which is 0 in most implementations, but is not standard as well.

To get the sizes just use `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(int)` etc.

Comment: Not exactly, look at unwind's answer. Assigning a pointer to NULL is a normal thing, using a pointer being NULL, like here, *without* dereferencing it is also a normal thing (eg `if (p == NULL)`). Now I agree this is not reasonable to make calculation with it (eg `p+1`), it *could* be UB on some systems (well, that;s the definition of UB :-), but,  here we enter the "likeness world", and the results produced by OP are not specifically surprising.

Comment: `p+1` is pointer arithmetic and it is undefined behavior with `p=NULL`.

Comment: *Pointer arithmetic on a pointer not pointing to an array is Undefined Behavior.* <- that's a bit too strong, though. Adding one is always ok, given the pointer was pointing to an object before. Apart from that, yes, it's UB, but the standard gives a hint this is because of possible overflow: "*If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined.*".

Comment: Arithmetic overflow is not the *only* reason for UB. On a system with segmented memory, like Windows 3, pointer arithmetic could also make you fall off the end of a segment.